# Error with output while finding repeated words in a string in C++

Tags: c++, maps

could you tell me why 1 is appearing in my output while I'm keeping track of words and occurrence in a given string using maps?

```
string x="Hello World Hello World";
//getline(cin,x);

map<string,int> store;
stringstream s(x);

do
{
    string y;
    s>>y;
    if(store.find(y)!=store.end())
    {
        auto it=store.find(y);
        it->second++;
    }
    else
        store.insert(pair<string,int>(y,1));
}while(s);
map<string, int>::iterator itr; //common for all maps

 for(itr=store.begin();itr!=store.end();++itr)
    cout<<itr->first<<" "<<itr->second<<endl;
```

Output:

```
 1
Hello 2
World 2
```

Comment: After you read the last `"World"`, `s` is still good. So the loop does another iteration. There, `s>>y` fails and `y` remains an empty string - but you process it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I rectified the else part of condition by using y.length()>0 and now it seems to be working fine.